# How to remove rows have ' - ' in their columns?

Tags: matlab, rows, cells

I have a cell array of size (37080*2) and I want to delete the rows have '-' in column 1 or 2.
    cell={'gif','ghf';'feh','-';'ACACA','BRCA1';'-','TBCD';'NKX3-1','ATXN1'}
Output wanted:
    {'gif','ghf';'ACACA','BRCA1';'NKX3-1','ATXN1'}

I have tried `strcmp` but I get only on error.

```
for row1 = 1:size(cell,1)
    if strcmp(cell(row1,1),'-')|| strcmp(cell(row1,2),'-')
        cell(row1,:) = [];
    end
end
```

Comment: oh sorry i forgot, i'm using MATLAB

Comment: @ Dukeling i have used that code

Comment: Hi Friends any help !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method should work.  [strcmp](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html)  works on cells and returns a matrix. then just use `any` over the 2nd dimension.

```
c={'gif','ghf';'feh','-';'ACACA','BRCA1';'-','TBCD';'NKX3-1','ATXN1'} 
c(any(strcmp(c,'-'),2),:)=[]
```

output:

3×2 cell array

```
'gif'       'ghf'  
'ACACA'     'BRCA1'
'NKX3-1'    'ATXN1'
```